# Referencing a javascript object from within its declaration

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Why is it possible to reference an object from within the object directly? For example:

```
var object = {
    prop1 : "Prop 1",
    prop2 : "Prop 2",
    func : _ => console.log(object)
}

object.func();
```

//output `{prop1: 'Prop 1', prop2: 'Prop 2', func: ƒ}`

Similarly I could do:

```
var object = {
    prop1 : "Prop 1",
    prop2 : "Prop 2",
    func : function() { console.log(this) }
}

object.func();
```

This will result in the same output as above. I am mainly trying to understand why it is legal to reference the variable name `object` from inside its declaration.

Comment: Why would you expect / want it to be illegal?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Comment: @Teemu this is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempts to access variables inside functions are not resolved until the function is **called** … which will be after the object is created.